# Downloading and Viewing CSV with Python

Tags: python, ftp

really new to python, was attempting to download a CSV through FTP. 
I've made the connection go to the right folder, but I want to also print the tables as well.

```
import pandas as pd 
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('f20-preview.xxx.com')
ftp.login(user='xxx_test', passwd = 'xxxxxxx')
ftp.cwd('/testfolder/')
def grabFile():

    filename = 'MOCK_DATA.csv'
    localfile = open(filename, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, localfile.write, 1024)
data = pd.read_csv(filename) 
data.head()
```

This causes a nameError, filename is not defined? Im ight be confusing myself so clarification would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are defining a function, never call it and afterwards you are expecting to find a variable defined inside that function.

One way to fix things would be to eliminate the  line with `def` completely.

A possibly better solution would be something like this

```
import pandas as pd 
from ftplib import FTP

# reusable method to retrieve a file
def grabFile(ftp_obj, filename):
    localfile = open(filename, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, localfile.write, 1024)

# connect to the ftp server
ftp = FTP('f20-preview.xxx.com')
ftp.login(user='xxx_test', passwd = 'xxxxxxx')
ftp.cwd('/testfolder/')


# then get files and work them

# having a "target file"
filename = 'MOCK_DATA.csv' 
# grab the file
grabFile(ftp, filename)
# work the file
data = pd.read_csv(filename) 
data.head()  
# now you could still use the same connected ftp object and grab another file, and so on
```

Comment: Not to mention the function doesn't `return` anything

Comment: seems to still give an error ?
TypeError: grabFile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
I tried looking into what it means but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: yes, you are right, I've forgot to pass the `ftp` object to the function, I've adjusted the code

Answer (score 1):

You did not call your "grabfile" function. But it appears the other answers helped alleviate that issue, so I will merely share some quality-of-life code for working with data sets

I often store my data files in a separate folder from the python code, so this can help you keep things straight and organized if you'd prefer to have the input data in another folder.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
original_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/home/user/RestOfPath/')
data = pd.read_csv('Filename')
os.chdir(original_dir)
data.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly use the absolute/full path instead of just the name for the CSV file? My guess is that it's looking in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

The working directory of your python script and the location which the CSV are stored need to be the same given the function you provided.

However, you do not call the function.

If you call the function and get the same error then it is likely that MOCK_DATA.csv is not in the location /testfolder/MOCK_DATA.csv you will run into issues.

The way to access this would be to delete def grabFile.